# This tag has hit rock [bottom]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

So... we have a [bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bottom) tag on SO. I propose we get rid of it.

Criteria for burnination:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is
   applied? And is it unambiguous?

   No, certainly not. There are tons of possible uses for "bottom". I guess it means the bottom of *something*, but that isn't super helpful or descriptive at all
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Depends on which definition we're going by. If it is referring to the bottom of a page, for example, maybe...? But it is really far to vague to be helpful as a tag
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   No, certainly not.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   Nope
5. Can someone be an expert in bottoms...?

   I'll leave that one un-answered in the interest of MSO remaining family-friendly

Comment: Additional info: from the oldest non-deleted questions, looks like the tag has already existed before [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62391213/2821954) (Jun 15, 2020) since the user doesn't have enough rep to create the tag, so it's unclear when the tag was first originated. Nevertheless, let's throw it to the bottomless pit...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The term "bottom" doesn't uniquely identify a specific programming topic in the least, so this tag should be burninated.

Given the fact that someone evidently edited out tags just to make this be below the threshold of 50 questions, it seems appropriate to follow the usual process of featuring this post before proceeding. That being said, this really doesn't seem like a difficult burnination, and I'd be surprised if anyone would actually defend this tag given an opportunity, so I suggest that we just feature it for the sake of process and then burninate it absent any objections.

Comment: I didn't notice this answer was posted, so props for that. I gave up when trying to compile a possible list of retagging targets after noticing multiple `android-` and `flutter-` tags related to "bottom" ...